# Can a constructor void creation of its own object?

Tags: c#

I'm using the following statement.

```
IEnumerable<Stuff> output = list.Entities.Select(
  element => new Stuff(element));
```

Sometimes the *element* is such that it needs not to be included, so I added a conditional.

```
IEnumerable<Stuff> output = list.Entities.Where(
  element => IsDecent(element)).Select(
    element => new Stuff(element));
```

Now, it just hit me that it might be even neater to skip the checker and cause the creation of a new *Stuff* to yield nada (return *null* or not returning anything at all), hence omitting the addition of the indecent elements. Or perhaps invoke the destructor automatically upon such a condition being met. Of course, the check needs then to be performed elsewhere, i.e. in the constructor of *Stuff*.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it recommended?
3. Is it widely applied?

Comment: I don't see any benefit for specializing objects for Linq. You could probably write your own Extension Methods for your objects for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the code that you're using now.  A `Where` and a `Select` is *much* better, from a usability perspective, then a `Select` that sometimes maps items to `null` (or some other "not a real item" placeholder) when they shouldn't be there in the first place.  You'll just need to get rid of, or ignore, those null items down the road.

You're doing two things; filtering items to those that meet a condition, and then mapping each item to another type of item.  Your code should reflect the fact that you're doing those two things.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to return anything but constructed object from new. You can throw from constructor thus blocking creation of a particular object, but one would have to handle such exception.

I would not recommend trying to block construction/destroy object while it is created - normally construction of an object is expected to succeed. Not calling constructor as suggested in other answers is much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

Yes It is possible. But condition verification is needed (Where clause will be shift to Select clause)

> Is it recommended?

I cannot recommend or not-recommend. But from code review point of view, it looks buggy and dodgy.

> Is it widely applied?

Not seen widely applied. [Null object pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) is better known.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. No'ish (depending on some extra-utlra-super-special circumstances it **might** be the best approach).
3. Never seen it. Cool thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask, observe that `new Nullable<int>()` returns `null`.

But I want to repeat [what Servy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14325000/284795)  - your current code is fine. Don't over-complicate it!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you have is probably the best.  But if you're set on combining them, you could use an extension method like this:

```
static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<U> SelectWhere<T, U>(
                    this IEnumerable<T> @this, 
                    Predicate<T> filter, 
                    Func<T, U> map) 
    {
        foreach (T element in @this) {
            if (filter(element)) yield return map(element);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
list.Entities.SelectWhere(IsDecent, element => new Stuff(element))
```